# How to add 2 columns with same id in 1 array in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie in php and mysql and I am trying to create a JSON API but I can't figure out something. My table is like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBnQA.png). What I am trying to do is to get only `first_name` and `last_name` values and add them to the same array. That's what I have tried:

```
<?php
require_once 'wp-connect.php';

$response = array();
if($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_users
    INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
    ORDER BY wp_posts.ID";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result){
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            
            $response[$i]['post_id'] = $row['ID'];
            $response[$i]['user_id'] = $row['post_author'];
            $response[$i]['post'] = $row['post_content'];
            $response[$i]['firstName'] = $row['meta_value'] = 'first_name';
            $response[$i]['lastName'] = $row['meta_value'] = 'last_name';
            $response[$i]['username'] = $row['user_nicename'];
            $response[$i]['post_date'] = $row['post_date'];
            $response[$i]['post_type'] = $row['post_type'];
            $response[$i]['post_title'] = $row['post_title'];
            $response[$i]['post_name'] = $row['post_name'];
            $i++;
        }
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
?>
```

This is how I want my JSON to look like:

```
{
        "post_id": "597",
        "user_id": "1",
        "post": "Hello world!!!",
        "firstName": "Achisyg",
        "lastName": "", //This is empty because last_name inside the table is empty too
        "username": "achisyg",
        "post_date": "2021-12-20 20:05:17",
        "post_type": "post",
        "post_title": "1-1-1640030717",
        "post_name": "1-1-1640030717"
    }
```

So, how is it possible to do what I need? I appreciate any answer!

Comment: What are you doing with `$row['meta_value']`? What happens with current code and what should happen?

Comment: @user3783243 `meta_value` is the row that saves the value of `first_name` and `last_name`. Thanks for the clarification. I will edit the question to make it clear!

Comment: @rider25 so you have `firstName` and `lastName` together in `meta_value` and want to separate them?

Comment: @FelixGerberding I want to add both of them to the json api array. As it is shown above.

Comment: I don't understand how your current code is failing you.  Are you asking how to JOIN a "pivoted" table?

Comment: @mickmackusa let me explain you. I want `first_name` to be shown here`"firstName": "Achisyg"` and `last_name` here `"lastName": ""`. However, with this code I have written `$response[$i]['firstName'] = $row['meta_value'] = 'first_name';
            $response[$i]['lastName'] = $row['meta_value'] = 'last_name';` it show in both first and last name the same value.

Comment: Please create a db-fiddle so that I can test my recommended solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until there is a dbfiddle demo, I will not test my sql, but I would create a subquery on a pivoted table -- this will flatten the rows of meta data and serve up the targeted name values in the result set.  My answer also includes some other miscellaneous refinements.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once 'wp-connect.php';

$result = [];
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT * 
FROM wp_users
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS first_name,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value, NULL)) AS last_name
    FROM wp_usermeta
    GROUP BY user_id
) pivoted ON pivoted.user_id = wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.ID
SQL;
foreach (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) as $row) {
    $result[] = [
        'post_id' => $row['ID'],
        'user_id' => $row['post_author'],
        'post' => $row['post_content'],
        'firstName' => $row['first_name'],
        'lastName' => $row['last_name'],
        'username' => $row['user_nicename'],
        'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
        'post_type' => $row['post_type'],
        'post_title' => $row['post_title'],
        'post_name' => $row['post_name'],
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```